# Apache Camel: do not trigger route if previous route run is not complete

Tags: java, timer, apache-camel

I have such a situation:

- Apache Camel route is triggered by timer
- route executes massive lengthy task
- and it is possible for timer to trigger route again while previous run is still underway.

I would like my route NOT to be re-triggered while massive task is underway. That is, timer may issue event but it should somehow not lead to trigger route.
When massive task is finished, it should be possible for timer to start route again.

What would be the best way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the route is still running when the timer fires?  Should the timer firing be ignored, so that the route will run on the next timer firing, or should the route wait for the previous invocation to finish and then run immediately after?

Comment: @JimNicholson I would like to have ignored

Answer (score 3):

Well, my first reflex would be to use the `timer`'s `period` option without the `fixedRate` option (i.e. set the `fixedRate` option to false):

So, declaring:

```
from("timer:myTask?[other_options]&fixedRate=false")
    .to("direct:lengthyProcessingRoute")
```

should wait for the task to complete before triggering the timer again.

For instance, declaring a route like (`fixedRate` is false by default):

```
from("timer:sender?delay=5s&period=3s")
        .log("Ping!")
        .delay(5000)
        .log("Ping2!");
```

will always give the output of:

```
2016-08-26 12:36:48.130  INFO 5775 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : Ping!
2016-08-26 12:36:53.133  INFO 5775 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : Ping2!
2016-08-26 12:36:53.135  INFO 5775 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : Ping!
2016-08-26 12:36:58.138  INFO 5775 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : Ping2!
```

However, this will only work if your lengthy processing route is synchronous in nature. If it's not, then you would have to do something similar to what JimNicholson is suggesting [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146377/4657798).

Comment: What do you mean by `synchronous in nature`? 

you mean if I had something like that

`
from("timer:sender?period=3s&fixedRate=false")
        .proccess(proccessor)
        .split(body())
        .parallelProcessing()
        .to("direct:to-route")
        .aggregate(aggregator)
        .end();
`
it won't wait for the whole route to aggregate to fire the next timer?

Comment: @monicamillad I think your route is still synchronous due to the aggregate (although the end may need to be moved to before the aggregate step). But if you had a processor that just scheduled the lengthy task on a background thread without waiting for completion then the route would finish processing the current trigger and the next one could fire before the background processing was done

Answer (score 3):

This is a dsl version that has worked for me:

```
private static final AtomicBoolean readyToProcess = new AtomicBoolean(true);

public static boolean readyToProcess() {
    boolean readyToProcess = AlarmRouteBuilder.readyToProcess.get();
    if (readyToProcess) {
        AlarmRouteBuilder.readyToProcess.set(false);
    }
    return readyToProcess;
}

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("timer://alarm-poll?period=5s").routeId("alarm-poll")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Start Timer")
            .filter(method(AlarmRouteBuilder.class, "readyToProcess"))
            .to("direct:alarm-dostuff")
            .end()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "End Timer")
    ;

    from("direct:alarm-dostuff").routeId("alarm-dostuff")
//            .process(exchange -> readyToProcess.set(false))
            .process(exchange -> doStuff())
            .process(exchange -> readyToProcess.set(true))
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a bean to hold the running/finished state of the route with methods to set the state and a method to test the state. Then I would do something like this:

```
<route>
  <from uri="timer:...">
  <filter>
    <method ref="routeStateBean" method="isStopped">
    <to uri="bean:routeStateBean?method=routeStarted"/>
    ....
    <to uri="bean:routeStateBean?method=routeStopped"/>
  </filter>
</route>
```

Comment: Could you please provide java code for the above xml ?